# Magento2: Create Module without Controller

Tags: magento2, module, controllers

How to create a simple module like HelloWorld in Magento2 without controller

Comment: were you want to show hello world ? if in admin config you can do this

Comment: i'm not sure where, i just wanted to know whether its possible or not to create module without controller. If so can you explain it. Thank in advance.

Comment: yes you can do it.. let me show you in few minutes...

Comment: @MohitKumarArora No,They did it with Controller i think so

Comment: yes it's possible to create module without controller.

Comment: @sathya  Msquare answer is works.

Answer (score 2):

I have cerated simple hello world module without controller

> Mag/HelloWorld/Block/HomePage.php

```
<?php
namespace Mag\HelloWorld\Block;

class HomePage extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getMessage()
    {
        $msg = "Hello World";
        return $msg;
    }
}
```

> Mag/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mag_HelloWorld" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> Mag/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Mag\HelloWorld\Block\HomePage" name="mg_helloworld_homepage_block" template="Mag_HelloWorld::homepage.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Mag/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/homepage.phtml

```
<h1><?php echo $block->getMessage();?></h1>
<p>Some content here</p>
```

> Mag/HelloWorld/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mag_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

And finally showing on home page check :-

[image]

Hope help this code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> here i create a widget module without contoller you can access it to insert widget in admin panel

**Vendor\Module\etc\registration.php**

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Vendor\Module\etc\module.xml**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Vendor\Module\etc\widget.xml**

**widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:widget:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget class="Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\Posts" id="widget_posts">
        <label>Simple Widget</label>
        <description>Posts</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="posts" sort_order="10" visible="true" xsi:type="text">
                <label>Custom Posts Label</label>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

**Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\Posts.php**

**Posts.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class Posts extends Template implements BlockInterface {

    protected $_template = "widget/posts.phtml";

}
```

**Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\widget\posts.phtml**

**posts.phtml**

```
<h1>Hello widget </h1>


<?php if($block->getData('posts')): ?>
    <h2 class='posts'><?php echo $block->getData('posts'); ?></h2>
    <p>This is sample widget. Perform your code here.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: yes this works. Thanks